# What do these compilation errors in Xcode mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Sorry I cannot be more descriptive, basically what happened is I went to open Xcode today (I'm a fairly new user) and was unable to test my build as I had these errors which I do not understand.  I don't understand why all of a sudden I'm getting these.  I can post full source if that would help anyone debug this.

[image]

my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface local405ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSTime *timer;
}

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
- (IBAction)homeButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)payDuesButton:(id)sender;
```

Comment: I'm willing to bet the root problem is coming from whatever header you're importing there....looks like `local405ViewController.h`

Comment: First, under your build options, do a "clean all".  Next, look "upstream" from the first error for something amiss -- a simple missing `;` or `}` can wreak havoc.  Look in includes included just before errors -- this is a prime place for missing terminators.

Comment: Dan I've added my viewcontroller.h for you to take a look at.

Comment: Just a small suggestion, always use CamelCase for Class names and start with with capital letters so that they do not get mistaken for method names. MyClassName vs. myMethodName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's your entire ViewController.h file, it looks like you're missing an `@end` directive to signify the end of the `@interface` block. (In fact, I hope that the real file is "local405ViewController.h".)

Comment: Thank you, yet another question with a simple answer.